# Convert dynamic csv to json containing List<string> C#

Tags: c#, json, csv, choetl

I want to serialize a list of strings in C#? I have previously successfully used an open-source library Cinchoo ETL for similar tasks, but I am stuck in this particular scenario. I do not want to use POCO since my source data structure is dynamic. I would much rather read the data from a csv and serialize it.

My source data in csv format:

```
id,name,friends/0,friends/1
1,Tom,Dick,Harry
```

Required output JSON - `{"id":1,"name":"Tom","friends":["Dick","Harry"]}`

Comment: The title and the content of the question confuse me. Do you want convert CSV to JSON or JSON to CSV?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855584/csv-to-nested-json-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Pac0 - I want to convert csv to json. However, since my source data structure is dynamic I will not use POCO. My eventual json format is what I have mentioned in the question. I am trying to understand if there are any opensource libraries so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Jabberwocky - slightly different requirement here - I just want a list of strings in the array - no attribute names required within the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, you can do with [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) as below

```
string csv = @"id,name,friends/0,friends/1
1,Tom,Dick,Harry";

StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter(json)
    .Configure(c => c.SupportMultipleContent = true)
    .Configure(c => c.SingleElement = true)
    )
{
    using (var r = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv).WithFirstLineHeader()
        .Configure(c => c.AutoArrayDiscovery = true)
        .Configure(c => c.ArrayIndexSeparator = '/')
        )
        w.Write(r);
}
Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "name": "Tom",
 "friends": [
  "Dick",
  "Harry"
 ]
}
```